# Apache2 - Hide target redirect URL in browser development tool

Tags: apache-2.4

Do you know if it is possible to hide the target URL where the source URL point to ?

I've made this redirection :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^(contoso.com)$
RewriteRule .* https://dadibou.com/sponsorship?code=$0 [R=301,L]
```

But when I enter https://contoso.com/code=mycode I can see in the browser's developper tool where this URL goes to.

Example :

[browser's developper tool view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBC83.png)

And I want that to be hidden, is that possible ?

Comment: You want a reverse proxy. See the Apache [Reverse Proxy Guide](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of redirecting a browser request:

- Server tells the Browser to use another URL for that request
- Server rewrites the original URL internally

Currently, you are using the first option, as specified by the `R=301` part in your RewriteRule. What you want to do however is a server rewrite (the second option) which you should get by dropping the `R=301` flag.

You can read more about the different possible flags for `mod_rewrite` in the [official documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html). You might as well want to have a look at the `P` flag.